# PowerShell Script For Creating Same Folders In Multiple Directories

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10

Current folder structure:

```
\\Server\Source\A1\A1 101\
\\Server\Source\A1\A1 102\

\\Server\Source\A2\A2 101\
\\Server\Source\A2\A2 102\

\\Server\Source\A3\A3 101\
\\Server\Source\A3\A3 102\
```

I need to be able to create 3 folders, A, B, and C, inside each of the second level folders under source (A1 101, A2 101, etc.). FolderDir.txt has A, B, C on their own line. Is there a better way other than the following? There are a LOT more sub directories than listed above:

```
Foreach($folder in Get-Content "C:\temp\folderDir.txt")
{
    New-Item "\\Server\Source\A1\A1 101\$folder" -ItemType directory
    New-Item "\\Server\Source\A1\A1 102\$folder" -ItemType directory
    New-Item "\\Server\Source\A2\A2 101\$folder" -ItemType directory
    New-Item "\\Server\Source\A2\A2 102\$folder" -ItemType directory
    New-Item "\\Server\Source\A3\A3 101\$folder" -ItemType directory
    New-Item "\\Server\Source\A3\A3 102\$folder" -ItemType directory
}
```

Thanks!  I'm still pretty new to PowerShell.

This is what I came up with:

```
Foreach($folder in Get-Content "C:\temp\folderDir.txt")
{
$lesson = Get-ChildItem -Path \\Server\Source\A*\*
New-Item $lesson\$folder -ItemType Directory
}
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
New-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'A'.
At line:4 char:1
+ New-Item $lesson\$folder -ItemType Directory
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (\\Server\Source...\A:String) [New-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateDirectoryIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

New-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'B'.
At line:4 char:1
+ New-Item $lesson\$folder -ItemType Directory
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (\\Server\Source...\B:String) [New-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateDirectoryIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

New-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'C'.
At line:4 char:1
+ New-Item $lesson\$folder -ItemType Directory
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (\\Server\Source...\C:String) [New-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateDirectoryIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

However, if I put -WhatIf command on the end (after "directory") it appears to be able to do what I want...

Comment: _"I've yet to find a way to do this"_  Can you post the code you have so far and point out where it is failing?

Comment: You are a bit unclear if you want to create the subfolders in **every** 2nd level folder below source or only the ones ending in 101,102. Instead of literally writing everyone single one, use `Get-CildItem` to iterate the folder structure and a `ForEach-Object` to issue the New-Item in each one.

Comment: Apologies. Every 2nd level folder under source. The numbers vary.  How would I write that, with Get-ChildItem, for it to place those new directories in every second level directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the folderlist is iterated over several times it should be read in first

untested:

```
$folderlist = Get-Content "C:\temp\folderDir.txt"
Get-ChildItem -Path '\\Server\Source\*\*' -Directory | ForEach-Object {
  ForEach ($folder in $folderlist){
    New-Item (Join-Path $_.FullName $folder) -ItemType directory -Force -WhatIf
  }
}
```

If the output look OK remove the `-WhatIf`